# Regexp: numbers and few special characters

Tags: javascript, regex

I am buried in a RegExp hell and can't find way out, please help me.

I need RegExp that matches only numbers (at least 1 number) and one of this characters: <, >, = (exactly one of them one time).

My reg. expression looks like this:

```
^[0-9]+$|^[=<>]{1}$
```

And I thought it should match when my string containts one or more digits and exactly 1 special character defined by me. But it doesn't act correctly. I think there might be problem with my start/end of string definition but Im not sure about that.

Examples that should pass include:

- `<1`
- `=2`
- `22>`
- `>1`
- `=00123456789`

Examples that should not pass this reg. exp.:

- `<<2`
- `==222`
- `<>=2`

Comment: You really need to present your question with examples. Most answers below misunderstood your question..:(

Comment: Yes, it was my bad. But I got where my mistake was, it was the OR operator separating regExps. So anyway it ends well

Comment: @OutOfSpaceHoneyBadger I've edited your question to include the examples. In regex questions it's critical to be as specific as possible. You also may want to list some strings which should *not* pass.

Comment: @p.s.w.g Thank you again. I edited in some examples that cannot pass my reg. exp.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I thought it should match when my string containts one or more digits and exactly 1 special character

No, the original pattern matches a string contains one or more digits ***or*** exactly 1 special character. For example it will match `123` and `=` but *not* `123=`.

Try this pattern:

```
^\d+[=<>]$
```

This will match that consists of one or more digits, followed by exactly one special character. For example, this will match `123=` but *not* `123` or `=`.

If you want your special character to appear before the number, use a pattern like this instead:

```
^[=<>]\d+$
```

This will match `=123` but *not* `123` or `=`.

---

**Update**

Given the examples you provided, it looks like you want to match any string which contains one or more digits and exactly one special character either at the beginning *or* the end. In that case use this pattern:

```
^([=<>]\d+|\d+[=<>])$
```

This will match `<1`, `=2`, `22>`, and `>1`, but *not* `123` or `=`.

Answer (score 1):

Just use `[0-9]+[=<>]`

Here are visualizers of your regexp and this one:

- http://www.regexper.com/#%5E%5B0-9%5D%2B%24%7C%5E%5B%3D%3C%3E%5D%7B1%7D%24
- http://www.regexper.com/#%5B0-9%5D%2B%5B%3D%3C%3E%5D

Answer (score 1):

Your regex says:

1 or more numbers OR 1 symbol

Also, the ^ and $ means the whole string, not contains. if you want a contains, drop them. I don't know if you have a space between the number and symbol, so put in a conditional space:

```
[0-9]+\s?[=<>]{1}
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work.

```
^[0-9]+[=<>]$
```

1 or more digits followed by "=<>".

Answer (score 1):

Try this regex:

```
^\d+[=<>]$
```

#### Description

[image: Regular expression visualization]

Answer (score 0):

This one:

`/^\d+[<>=]$|^[<>=]\d+$/`

Comment: updated. However, whether `foo1=bar` matches still depends what OP wants